# Problema con GUI QtDesigner

Tags: python, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica, qt-designer

Estoy desarrollando una GUI con QtDesigner para correrla con python3 y PyQt5. Pues bien, cuando lo corro en Mac, se ve según lo he diseñado, pero cuando lo hago en linux o windows se ve muy reducido según se ve en las dos imágenes que adjunto. Por mas vueltas que le he dado, no consigo averiguar a que se debe ese desajuste. Si alguien me puede echar una mano, se lo agradecería enormemente, pues ya me he quedado sin recursos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro... A continuación añado el código y el archivo .ui

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

class Altas_form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi("altas.ui", self)

        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Save).clicked.connect(self.grabarDatos)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Close).clicked.connect(self.cerrar)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Reset).clicked.connect(self.reseteaDatos)
        self.txt_dni.setInputMask("99.999.999->A;_")
        self.txt_tip.setInputMask(">A-99999->A;_")
        self.txt_iniciales.setInputMask(">AAAA")

    def grabarDatos(self):

        empleo = self.cbx_empleo.currentText()
        idEmpleo = self.cbx_empleo.currentIndex()
        nombre = self.txt_nombre.text().strip().upper() # .strip quita espacios introducidos por error, delante y atras del texto
        apellido1 = self.txt_apellido1.text().strip().upper()
        apellido2 = self.txt_apellido2.text().strip().upper()
        dni = self.txt_dni.text().strip()
        tip = self.txt_tip.text().strip()
        iniciales = self.txt_iniciales.text().strip()
        nombCompleto = nombre + " " + apellido1 + " " + apellido2

        if nombre =="" or apellido1=="" or apellido2=="" or dni=="" or tip=="" or iniciales=="":
            mensaje = QMessageBox.warning(self, '', "Debes completar todos los campos\nno puede quedar ninguno vacío.")

        else:
    
            texto = ('Son correctos los siguientes datos: \n \n {} \n {} {} {} \n {} \n {} \n {}'.format(empleo, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, tip, iniciales))
    
            mensaje = QMessageBox.question(self, '', texto, QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
            #mensaje.setText('Son correctos los siguientes datos: \n \n {} \n {} {} {} \n {} \n {}'.format(empleo, nomb, ape1, ape2, dn, ti))
    
            if mensaje == QMessageBox.Yes:
                
                conexion = sqlite3.connect('usuarios.db')
                cur = conexion.cursor()
    
                sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (NULL, '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(empleo, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, tip, nivel, iniciales, idEmpleo, nombCompleto)
                cur.execute(sql)
    
                conexion.commit()
                conexion.close()
                self.close()

        self.txt_nombre.setFocus()
        return False

#--------------función para crear la BD si no existe--------------------
    def creaDB(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect('usuarios.db')
        cur = conexion.cursor()
        cur.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE usuarios (
            "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
            "empleo" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            "nombre" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            "apellido1" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            "apellido2" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            "dni" VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            "tip" VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            "nivel" INTEGER,
            "iniciales" VARCHAR(4),
            "idEmpleo" INTEGER,
            "nombCompleto" VARCHAR(60))
            ''')

    def cerrar(self):
        self.close()

    def reseteaDatos(self):
        
        self.cbx_empleo.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.txt_nombre.clear()
        self.txt_apellido1.clear()
        self.txt_apellido2.clear()
        self.txt_dni.clear()
        self.txt_tip.clear()
        self.txt_iniciales.clear()
        self.txt_nombre.setFocus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Altas_form()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Y este es el archivo .ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Alta</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Alta">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>421</width>
    <height>376</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>421</width>
    <height>376</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>421</width>
    <height>376</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>FORMULARIO DE DIETAS COLECTIVO</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>180</x>
     <y>330</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Close|QDialogButtonBox::Reset|QDialogButtonBox::Save</set>
   </property>
   <property name="centerButtons">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>193</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>201</width>
     <height>251</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbx_empleo">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>9</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 1</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 2</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 3</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 4</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 5</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 6</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 7</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 8</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 9</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>EMPLEO 10</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_nombre">
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>20</number>
      </property>
      <property name="placeholderText">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_apellido1">
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>20</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_apellido2">
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>20</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_dni">
      <property name="toolTip">
       <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Por favor introduce el DNI con la letra.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="inputMask">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>12</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_tip">
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>9</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_iniciales">
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>4</number>
      </property>
      <property name="placeholderText">
       <string>Iniciales del nombre completo</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>23</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>160</width>
     <height>251</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_empleo">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Empleo:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_nombre">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Nombre:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_apellido1">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Primer Apellido:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_apellido2">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Segundo Apellido:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_dni">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>D.N.I.:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_tip">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TIP:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_iniciales">
      <property name="text">
       <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;Iniciales:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>52</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>315</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="lineWidth">
    <number>2</number>
   </property>
   <property name="midLineWidth">
    <number>-1</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>22</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_title">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>9</x>
      <y>5</y>
      <width>381</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;ALTA NUEVA&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <zorder>frame</zorder>
  <zorder>buttonBox</zorder>
  <zorder>verticalLayoutWidget</zorder>
  <zorder>verticalLayoutWidget_2</zorder>
  <zorder>frame_2</zorder>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: hola amig@ bienvenid@ a stackoverflow te recomiendo que te leas este articulo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo, así lo haré, espero ir aprendiendo poco a poco.

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@, podrías facilitar el código del programa y el archivo .ui del diseño en Qt Creator?

Comment: Hecho, acabo de incluir los dos archivos que me solicitas. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido,

Acabo de replicar tu código y no me da el error, es decir el diseño que veo en QtDesigner es igual al resultado obtenido en la ejecución, aún así hay varias cosas que no termino de comprender en tu diseño de la UI que pueden dar lugar a lo que está ocurriendo, básicamente relacionadas todas con el layout de los widgets.

1. Widget principal QDialog Alta sin layout
2. Dos QFrame innecesarios a priori y ambos sin layout también.

**Posible solución**

Eliminar los widgets innecesarios y forzar el layout en el widget principal, adicionalemente limito la altura del texto *lbl_title* (**QLabel**) para que sean los **QVBoxLayout** los que crezcan verticalmente, quedando *altas.ui* así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Alta</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Alta">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>421</width>
    <height>376</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>421</width>
    <height>376</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>421</width>
    <height>376</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>FORMULARIO DE DIETAS COLECTIVO</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="4" column="0">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_empleo">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Empleo:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_nombre">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Nombre:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_apellido1">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Primer Apellido:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_apellido2">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Segundo Apellido:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_dni">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>D.N.I.:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignRight">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_tip">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TIP:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_iniciales">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;Iniciales:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="1">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbx_empleo">
       <property name="currentIndex">
        <number>9</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 1</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 2</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 3</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 4</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 5</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 6</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 7</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 8</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 9</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>EMPLEO 10</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_nombre">
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>20</number>
       </property>
       <property name="placeholderText">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_apellido1">
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>20</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_apellido2">
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>20</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_dni">
       <property name="toolTip">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Por favor introduce el DNI con la letra.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="inputMask">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>12</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_tip">
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>9</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="txt_iniciales">
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>4</number>
       </property>
       <property name="placeholderText">
        <string>Iniciales del nombre completo</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="5" column="0" colspan="2">
    <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="standardButtons">
      <set>QDialogButtonBox::Close|QDialogButtonBox::Reset|QDialogButtonBox::Save</set>
     </property>
     <property name="centerButtons">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_title">
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>16777215</width>
       <height>30</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>14</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;ALTA NUEVA&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Como comentaba en el primer momento, solamente me ocurre en linux y en windows, en mac aparece correctamente.
Por otro lado, según me indicas, seguramente tenga que ver con los layout, sobre todo el principal, que si que es verdad que no había echado cuenta de que faltaba. Los otros dos que me haces referencia, son solamente estéticos para diferenciar partes del título, y botones. Seguramente exista otra manera de hacerlo, tengo que seguir estudiando más sobre este maravilloso programa de creación de GUIs.

Comment: @PokeP también te pasa con el UI que te he pasado? O con ese no te ocurre?

Comment: Me temo que no, el problema persiste, al menos en linux. En windows no he tenido oportunidad de probarlo, sin embargo en MAC funciona sin problema, al igual que mi versión.